# How to generate absolute URL for breadcrumbs?

Tags: 8, blocks, navigation, breadcrumbs

I am use [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module for a D8 site. I have everything I need with this module as it alters the existing Breadcrumb block, but it outputs relative URLs.

How can I change the relative URLs to absolute?

Current issue (Breadcrumb Output):

```
<ol>
<li>
    <a href="/level-one">level One</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/level-one/level-two">level two</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/level-one/level-two/level-three">level three</a>
</li>
<li>
Current Level
</li>
</ol>
```

Expected output:

```
<ol>
<li>
    <a href="https://www.domain.com/level-one">level One</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="https://www.domain.com/level-one/level-two">level two</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="https://www.domain.com/level-one/level-two/level-three">level three</a>
</li>
<li>
Current Level
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the breadcrumbs of other bread crumb builders (core or contrib) in a [hook_system_breadcrumb_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_system_breadcrumb_alter/8.4.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_system_breadcrumb_alter().
 */
function mymodule_system_breadcrumb_alter(\Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb, \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $context) {
  $links = $breadcrumb->getLinks();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $url = $link->getUrl();
    $url->setAbsolute();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was reviewing url::setOption and stumbled upon url::setAbsolute and couldn't figure out which one is prefered. I understand that setOption takes in two parameters, but setAbsolute also works except it specifically takes 1 parameter and always sets the absolute to True (assuming default is used) or false if that is passed. What would be recommended?

Comment: Both do the same, but since the specific method exists, why not use it? I'll change it in the code.

Comment: I have used the setAbsolute() method. It works in all my test cases.